# インスタンスの生成回数を繰り返し処理を使って表したい

Tags: java

**コードや質問文の方少し長くなると思いますが、ご了承ください。**

---

現在、4人の人間をオブジェクト指向を用いてコンストラクタとして生成し、生成した回数だけその人の「名前、年齢、身長、体重」などを出力するプログラムを作ろうとしています。
以下が*Main.java*からインスタンスの情報を受け取った*Person.java*のコードです。
後に*Person.java*のコードを活用し*Main.java*でそれぞれの情報を出力します。

しかし、*Main.java*のコメント分にも書いてあるように、一人生成する毎に*Main.java*で沢山のコードを書かなければいけなく、後にもっと人数が増えたときに
・人数の記憶が困難になる
・増えるにつれてもっと膨大な量のコードを書かなければならない
と言う問題が起きることを推測しました。

---

(以下コード)

**Person.java：**

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    public static int count = 0;  //生成回数を設定
    
    Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age, double height, double weight) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        count++;
    }
   public String getFullName() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
   }
   public int getAge() {
       return this.age;
   }
   public double getHeight() {
       return this.height;
   }
   public double getWeight() {
       return this.weight;
   }
    
}
```

---

**Main.java：**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Person person1 = new Person("Aくん","鈴木",20,176,64);
        Person person2 = new Person("Bさん","佐々木",21,178,65);
        Person person3 = new Person("Cさん","山田",22,185,63);
        Person person4 = new Person("Dくん","横山",23,180,60);
        
        
        System.out.println("person1の名前は " + person1.getFullName());
        System.out.println("person1の年齢は" + person1.getAge());
        System.out.println("person1の身長は" + person1.getHeight());
        System.out.println("person1の体重は" + person1.getWeight());
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        
        System.out.println("person2の名前は " + person2.getFullName());
        System.out.println("person2の年齢は" + person2.getAge());//………とコンストラクタが生成された回数分出力する
         /*以下省略*/
        }
}
        /*…………のように一人ひとり生成する度に沢山のコードを書かなければいけない*/
```

---

そこで、for文などを使って生成回数される毎に繰り返し処理をするプログラムを作ろうと図りますが、例えば

```
for(int i = 1; i<Person.count+1; i++){
            System.out.println("person" + i + "の名前は" + person(/*ここにpersonの数を書きたい*/).getFullName());
            /*以下省略しますが年齢、身長、体重などを書く*/
        }
```

と言う風に書き込んだときに、`person〇〇.getFullName()`と生成回数を書くときに、手が止まってしまいます。

`person(i).getFullName()`や`person(Person.count).getFullName()`と入力しても、
`cannnot find symbol`とエラーが起きてしまいます。

そこで、以上のことから、
**・コンストラクタの生成回数が1増えるごとに生成された数だけ繰り返し処理を書く**
(コードの書く量が減る、効率的な）
**プログラムを書くにはどのようにすればいいのか**

を教えていただければ恐縮です。

まだ文章を書くことに慣れておらず、以上の質問文に無駄な部分や分かりづらい箇所があるところも多いと思いますが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

配列や`ArrayList`を使うのがいいでしょう。

ArrayListでの生成

```java
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
list.add(new Person("Aくん","鈴木",20,176,64));
list.add(new Person("Bさん","佐々木",21,178,65));
...
```

ArrayListでの参照

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("person" + (i + 1) + "の名前は" + list.get(i).getFullName());
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！オブジェクト生成時にArrayListを使えることは初めて知りました！

Comment: 「オブジェクト生成時にArrayListを」使っているのではなく、list#add()にnew Person()を渡しているだけでperson1 = new Person()しているのとそんなに変わらないですよ。オブジェクトを生成するというのが何を意味しているのかよく考えてみるのがいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。もうすこしオブジェクト生成についての意味を理解して、これから質問しようと思います。MNEMOさんが言っていることを別の言い方で表現するとperson1 = new Person()と言う処理をArrayListにまとめてlistと言う変数でオブジェクト生成回数をカウントしていると言うことでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: オブジェクトの生成とは純粋にnew（コンストラクタ）を呼び出すことを指します。その生成されたインスタンスを何に保管するかは一個ずつ変数を用意するかListに追加してListで管理するか、あるいは配列で宣言して配列として管理するか、みたいな話ですね。countみたいな値で「生成回数」をカウントしても（消えるオブジェクトもあるので）あまり意味はないです。生成したオブジェクトを管理するところの動作を把握するという方向から学んで見ると良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

コード量が少なくて見通しが付きやすいという意味では、

```java
Person[] people = {
    new Person("Aくん","鈴木",20,176,64),
    new Person("Bさん","佐々木",21,178,65),
    new Person("Cさん","山田",22,185,63),
    new Person("Dくん","横山",23,180,60),
};
```

とするのが良いでしょう。こう書いたあとでListがほしければList.of(people)することで対応できます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。こういうやり方も確かにあるなぁと感心しました。